# Strange "at sign" symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

The @ symbol is not coming as I wish. I want to have the classical symbol, like the one visualized here. I tried in normal text and math mode but it is the same.

With the code below, I am not getting the symbol I want. I post images of both symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}
@
$@$

\end{document}
```

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image: What i get]

Comment: Maybe `\emph{@}` would do the trick?

Comment: That's simply a different font. With `\usepackage{newtxtext}` you'll get the desired output but all fonts will become Times-like.

Comment: I think it's worth someone saying this: **fonts are carefully designed to form a cohesive whole, and if you're going to switch fonts for a single character you should have a good reason** (beyond merely not being used to the symbol in the font you are using). I too found the Computer Modern @ sign unusual when I first saw it but I got used to it, and I would find it jarring and strange if I noticed you used (say) a Times @, or a bold @, in a Computer Modern text at regular weight.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's up to the font designer to decide how a particular glyph should be rendered in their font.

You can decide to borrow a particular symbol from another font, though. It seems that your preference goes for the symbol in Times, so the simplest strategy is to do

```
\newcommand{\myfavoriteat}{{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont @}}
```

and to use `\myfavoriteat` (or whatever name you prefer).

You *might* also decide to make `@` active so to be able to simply type `@`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\protected\def\myfavoriteat{%
  {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont @}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`@ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\myfavoriteat
\catcode`@=\active

\begin{document}

This is @.

This is \symbol{`@} (original in the font)

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you go with the active character approach, don't blame me if something goes wrong. I did warn you.

Comment: +1 for the warning

Answer (score 5):

`\textit{@}` and/or `\textsl{@}`, along with their **bold** variants, may provide what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % 'Latin Modern' is a clone of 'Computer Modern'

\begin{document}
@ \textit{@} \textsl{@} \textit{\textbf{@}} \textsl{\textbf{@}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change the font but just want the symbol, you can add \usepackage{marvosym} to your preamble, and then use the command \MVAt to make the @ symbol.